# How to update linear regression line with live data

Tags: python, pandas, websocket, scikit-learn

I'm retrieving live data to use it for further processing in a dataframe.
The first part (`get_binance_bars` function)gets the historical data where a linear regression line is fitted.
Now, I would like to have the linear regression line to be updated whenever the websocket receives data in. The changing live data is in `df['live_price']`.
How would you do this?

```
import websocket, json
import requests  
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt  
from datetime import datetime, date
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


symbol = "ETHUSDT"  
tf = "1m"

now = datetime.now()
today = date.today()

d = int(today.strftime("%d"))
m = int(today.strftime("%m"))
y = int(today.strftime("%Y"))
hr = int(now.strftime("%H"))
mn = int(now.strftime("%M"))


def get_binance_bars(ticker, interval, startTime, endTime):

    url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines"

    startTime = str(int(startTime.timestamp() * 1000))
    endTime = str(int(endTime.timestamp() * 1000))
    limit = '1000'

    req_params = {"symbol" : ticker, 'interval' : interval, 'startTime' : startTime, 'endTime' : endTime, 'limit' : limit}

    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(requests.get(url, params = req_params).text))

    if (len(df.index) == 0):
        return None
    
    df = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
    df.columns = ['time', 'high', 'low', 'close']
    df.close = df.close.astype("float")
    df.low = df.low.astype("float")
    df.high = df.high.astype("float")
    
    global Y_pred
    X = df.time.iloc[-20:].values.reshape(-1, 1)  
    Y = df.close.iloc[-20:].values.reshape(-1, 1)  

    linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  
    linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  
    Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X) 
    df['Y_pred'] = np.nan
    df.iloc[-20:, df.columns.get_loc('Y_pred')] = Y_pred
      
    df.time = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1000.0) for x in df.time] 
    df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True) #cut last row to prevent double bar with live data
    return df


SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/"+symbol.lower()+"@kline_"+tf

df = get_binance_bars(symbol, tf, dt.datetime(y, m, d, hr-hr, mn), dt.datetime(y, m, d, hr, mn)) #define how many bars, hr-1 = 60 bars


def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
 
    global df
    global time_plot
    global close
    global low
    global high
    
    json_message = json.loads(message)

    high = float(json_message['k']['h'])
    low = float(json_message['k']['l'])
    close = float(json_message['k']['c'])
    time_plot = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(json_message['k']['t']/1000).strftime('%H:%M')

    df['live_price'] = close
   
    df.iloc[-20:, df.columns.get_loc('Y_pred')] = Y_pred #<--- DOESN'T WORK

    print(df)        

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to use [Plotly](https://plotly.com/) for this sort of work. Please have a look at the [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates) component with Interval for updating the graphs and plots. It would be useful in the longer run and making the dashboards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't need to plot it. I need the data in my dataframe